# In swift, make a class with property declarations?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert my Objective C app to Swift. I have a class:

```
@interface XYUser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bio;

+ (XYUser)currentUser;

@end
```

Then I have an implementation:

```
@implementation XYUser

+ (XYUser)currentUser {
     XYUser *user = [[XYUser alloc] init];
     user.name = @"Bob Jim";
     user.bio = @"Hey all, I like to program!";
     return user;
}

@end
```

How could I do this in swift? I want to be able to do `XYUser.currentuser()`
 or be able to create one like:

```
var jim = XYUser()
jim.name = "Jim"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a [code translation service](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/2792531).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is few tips to consider when you translating code into Swift:

- You don't need class prefixes is Swift, use simple User.
- Value types are preferred over reference types. Use structs instead of classes.

The simplest solution is:

```
struct User  {
  var name: String
  var bio: String

  static func currentUser() -> User {
    let user = User(name: "Sam", bio: "I'm sam")
    return user
  }
}

extension User {
  init() {
    name = ""
    bio = ""
  }
}

// Use example
var user = User(name: "Sam", bio: "I'm sam")
user.name = "Jim"

var current = User.currentUser()

var empty = User()
empty.name = "Lolly"
```

Comment: Where would the function currentUser go and how would it be configured?

Comment: Where has it been suggested or recommended that prefixes are unnecessary for Swift?  Also, I can't agree with your second point... `structs` are when you want a value type over a reference type, and this isn't going to necessarily always be data structures.  And finally, why have you unnecessarily put `init()` in an extension...?

Comment: 1 - Swift has a namespace. It add project name as a default namespace. So the user class would look like: MyProject.User

2 - Structs are preferred. Value types are preferred than reference. Swift library has over 20 values types (String, array, Dictionary, Int) - it's all value type. 
https://realm.io/news/andy-matuschak-controlling-complexity/

3 - Struct provides memberwise default initializer If you don't create your own one. If you create it in the extension you will have both.

Comment: [Namespacing is implicit in swift, all classes (etc) are implicitly scoped by the module (Xcode target) they are in. no class prefixes needed](https://twitter.com/clattner_llvm/status/474730716941385729)